# How to change a files permissions through a prompt using bash scripting

Tags: bash, terminal, scripting, permissions

just started to learn how to script and Im trying to make a loop script which will automatically change the permissions of the requested file and ask the user again if they want to change another files permissions. So far this is what I have although I'm not entirely sure how to fully make the loop to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
until "$input"=no
do
    echo "Enter the name of file to change permissions"
    read filename
    chmod 777 $filename
    echo "$filename permissions has been changed"
    echo "Would you like to change the permissions of another file?(yes or no)"
    read $input
done
    echo "You typed: $input"
```

Comment: Use `[ "$input" = 'no' ]` instead of `"$input"=no`, quote `$filename` and drop that `$` from `read $input`. Or just go read a tutorial on loops and conditional constructs

Comment: you should update your question with the results of running your code; for example, for the current code I'm guessing you get a message like `-bash: =no: command not found`, which in turn is addressed by oguz's comment; next issue is probably going to be your 'read' commands ... you have 2 of these but one is incorrectly referencing the variable in which to store the response (hint: try running your code through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to validate your syntax); then there's (at least) one logic bug ... what happens if user enters an invalid/non-existent filename?

Comment: Awesome thank you! oguz's suggestion helped and fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to oguz's anwser I solved my problem, Use [ "$input" = 'no' ] instead of "$input"=no, quote $filename and drop that $ from read $input. Or just go read a tutorial on loops and conditional constructs